# Errors 2676 and 2784 (...could not deduce template argument for...) when inserting vector of structs into set

Tags: c++, vector, struct, operators

I am getting the following build errors when I try to run my program (in VS):

```
Error   10  error C2676: binary '<' : 'const move' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
Error   4   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from 'const move'
Error   8   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const move'
Error   1   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const move'
Error   3   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const move'
Error   5   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const move'
Error   6   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const move'
Error   9   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const move'
Error   7   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const move'
Error   2   error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from 'const move'
```

I have no idea why they are occurring, as I haven't defined any operators in my `move` struct (see below), nor are there any operators in the part of my code that causes it.

They seem to be caused by this function (which is never called):

```
std::set<solution> solve(grid board, solution prev) {
    std::set<solution> ret = {};
    ret.insert(prev);    
    return ret;
}
```

My typedefs/structs that are used above:

```
struct move {
public:
    move(unsigned startX, unsigned startY, unsigned endX, unsigned endY) {
        x0 = startX;
        y0 = startY;
        x1 = endX;
        y1 = endY;
    }
    unsigned x0 : 4, y0 : 4, x1 : 4, y1 : 4;
};

typedef std::vector<std::vector<__int8>> grid;
typedef std::pair<__int8, __int8> point;
typedef std::vector<move> solution;
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and what I can do to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using `set<solution>`, which is `set<vector<move>>`. `std::set` is sorted, hence it needs `operator<`. `std::vector` then passes it through to `move`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two more things in Steephen's answer that just don't fit. The first is mostly formal, `std::set` uses `std::less` by default, not `operator<`. This only matters in cornercases though, because `std::less` uses `operator<` by default. There is a different issue though, and that merits a different answer, because I can't format code properly in a comment.

When passing a custom comparator to `std::set` as second template parameter, you must make sure that it defines a strict-weak ordering. That means that the comparator `cmp` must satisfy certain requirements. In particular `cmp(a, a) = false` and `cmp(a, b) -> not cmp(b, a)`, which is used by the set (but also e.g. `std::map`) to determine equality. If `cmp(a, b) = false` and `cmp(b, a) = false` ("neither is less than the other"), it will treat the two values as equal.

Concerning the vector that you have, one suggestion was to use the euclidean distance. The euclidean distance between `(3, 0)` and `(0, 4)` is 5, as is that between `(0, 3)` and `(4, 0)`, `(0, 0)` and `(-5, 0)` and infinitely many others. That means that different vectors would be considered equal, which is probably not what you wanted.

As a rule of thumb, a lexicographical sorting is a good default. In order to implement that, you simply split the operands into tuples so that each tuple value can be compared numerically. The implementation then looks like this:

```
bool compare_move(move const& m1, move const& m2)
{
    if (m1.x0 != m2.x0) return m1.x0 < m2.x0;
    if (m1.y0 != m2.y0) return m1.y0 < m2.y0;
    if (m1.x1 != m2.x1) return m1.x1 < m2.x1;
    return m1.y1 < m2.y1;
}
```

This also has the advantage that it doesn't use floating-point math. It could be improved a bit using the fact that you have bitfields with just 4 bit, so every move only occupies 16 bit of data. If you combine those to a single integer value by shifting and OR'ing them, you would get the same, but I'm not sure if that microoptimization is even worth it.

Answer (score 1):

std::set creates a binary tree internally using comparison operator `<` by default, that is the reason you got the error specified in your question. So std::set has to keep an order internally for all its elements. So each time we insert, it will check new elements order among existing elements using comparison operator and position it accordingly.

You have to define  operator `<` as follows inside struct move before doing insertion to std::set. I hope you can compare using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance

```
bool move::operator <(struct move & rhs)
{
  return (  sqrt( (this->x1-this->x0)* (this->x1-this->x0) +
                  (this->y1-this->y0) * (this->y1-this->y0) ) <
           sqrt( (rhs.x1-rhs.x0)* (rhs.x1-rhs.x0) +
                  (rhs.y1-rhs.y0) * (rhs.y1-rhs.y0) ) );

}
```

If you prefer to keep a custom comparison in place of `<`, you can do it as follows. Define your comparison operator 'customcompare` and define std::set as follows:

```
std::set<std::vector<move>,customcompare> ret;
```

Comment: If the OP needs a comparison function (i.e., they don't alter their design to avoid this issue altogether) then [taxicab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry)/[Manhattan](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) distance would probably work just as well.

Comment: Can you clarify this for me? Am I right in saying that this function is needed because `set` compares the objects and puts them in order by whether or not each object is greater?

Comment: @ricky3350 std::set is trying to create a binary tree internally using comparison operator, so it has to keep an order internally for all its elements. So each time we insert it will check its order among elements and position it accordingly. `operator <` is the default operator for std::set.

Comment: It's giving me the error `expression must have pointer type` on `rhs`

Comment: This completely ignores the fact that there is nowhere a `set<move>` in view. The suggested answer fixes the issue though, because `set<vector<T>>` uses a lexicographic comparison on the vectors and those in turn rely on a comparison for `T`, defaulting to `operator <`. Passing a comparator for `move`s to `set<>` won't work though, you need a comparator for `vector<move>`s there. BTW: Why are you prefixing `move` with `struct`? It shouldn't collide with `std::move`.